# access query to insert records from another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

Quick one I hope...I am struggling with an Access Query

I need to copy values from *Table A* into *Table B* **ONLY** if they don't already exist in *Table B* using the `MTR#` field to determine if exists.

The query will also need to increment `tB.ImgRefNum` up one from the previous record when inserting.

I need to copy

```
tA.MTR# to tB.MTR# 
tA.MTRF1 to tB.Item 
tA.MTRF2 to tB.PONum 
tA.MTRF3 to tB.DateRecv **BUT need to cast from text YYYYMMDD to date format)

Table A 
TRX Number (number) 
MTR#       (number) 
MTRF1      (text) 
MTRF2      (text) 
MTRF3      (text)   *A date is stored here but textually as YYYYMMDD

Table B 
ImgRefNum  (number) 
MTR#       (number)  
Item       (text) 
W          (number)
L          (number)
Vendor     (text)
PONum      (number)
DateRecv   (date)
```

Anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Why don't you make ImgRefNum an autonumber type?
Is MTR# set as Index No duplicates? Advise not to use any spaces or punctuation/special characters (underscore only exception) in names. Better would be MTR_Num.

Comment: ImgRefNum isn't auto-numbered and i can't alter the DB design at this point :( (it was someone else's program)

Comment: Sorry, technically MTR# is MTRNumber my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following SQL query (don't know exactly what part you were struggling with, so can't provide a specific explanation):

```sql
INSERT INTO tB (tB.ImgRefNum, tB.MTR#, tB.Item, tB.PONum, tB.DateRecv)
SELECT (SELECT Max(tB.ImgRefNum)+1 FROM tB) As NewRef, tA.MTR#, tA.MTRF1, tA.MTRF2, DateSerial(CInt(Mid(tA.MTRF2, 1, 4)),CInt(Mid(tA.MTRF2, 5, 2)), CInt(Mid(tA.MTRF2, 7, 2) ))
FROM tA
WHERE (SELECT Count(s.MTR#) FROM tB AS s WHERE s.MTR# = a.MTR#) = 0
```

Obviously, it is essential that `MTRF3` always contains a valid date string exactly formatted `YYYYMMDD`, else you will run into errors.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this quick. It was the part to check if exists already in TB.

Comment: How do i increment the tB.ImgRefNum since it's not configured as an autonumber (unable to change this design in the db)

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that shortly. Appreciate it alot!

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the familiar [`NOT EXISTS`, `LEFT JOIN NULL`, `NOT IN`](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&q=not+exists+vs+not+in+vs+left+outer+join&oq=not+exists+vs+not+in+vs+left+outer+join) queries with wrangling for your date and max time. Below uses the `NOT EXISTS` approach and assumes you use month-first dates `MM/DD/YYYY` (US-based):

```
INSERT INTO tB ([ImgRefNum], [MTR#], [Item], [PONum], [DateRecv])    
SELECT (SELECT Max(sub.[ImgRefNum]) FROM tA sub) + 1, 
       tA.[MTR#], tA.[MTRF1], tA.[MTRF2], 
       CDate(Mid(tA.[MTRF3], 5, 2) & "/" & Mid(tA.[MTRF3], 7, 2) & "/" &
             LEFT(tA.[MTRF3], 4))
FROM tA
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1 FROM tB sub WHERE sub.[MTR#] = tA.[MTR#])
```

Comment: You can either use the YYYY/MM/DD format that just always properly casts when using `CDate`, or `Dateserial`, but I don't see why you would go MM/DD/YYYY when that can cause issues, especially when the string already is YYYY/MM/DD and I've already shared a `Dateserial` approach

Comment: Indeed, `CDate()` can take multiple inputs. Either way I still have to include the `/`.